# Prism MEF Export / Import Problem

Tags: import, export, prism, mef

I´m trying to inject an existing instance of a class into my view, but the view only receive a default instance of my class.

Here is my export in a view model class

```
 [Export("BLA", typeof(vmObject))]
    public vmObject VMObject
    {
        get
        {
            return vmObject;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != vmObject)
            {
                vmObject = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged<vmObject>(() => this.VMObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

On demand, my view model loads another view which should receive the exported class.
I already have checked that class vmObject has been initialized as expected

```
tRegionManager.RequestNavigate("vInfoAuthorizationField", new Uri("/vInfoAuthorizationField", UriKind.Relative));
```

My import

```
[Import("BLA", AllowRecomposition = true, AllowDefault = false)]
    public vmObject VMObject { get; set; }
```

How can i fix this?

**Update**
I could solve the problem by myself

I added the following line to the bootstrapper

```
 this.Container.ComposeExportedValue(this.Container);
```

After that, I could import the CompositionContainer into my view model and following method solved the import / export problem

```
this.container.ComposeExportedValue("BLA",this.VMObject);
```

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it so others can see too.